# Force the output of neural network to be sorted

Tags: tensorflow

I have an output layer of shape `(None, 9)`, I want the first three numbers to be sorted.

I guess this is quite a common problem, I need help to implement it. Here various options

1. I could add a regularization in the loss to force the trainig to converge to such a solution, problably not so easy
2. to redefine the output as

```
x[2] = x[0] + abs(x[2])
x[1] = x[0] + abs(x[1])
```

I guess I can use the Lambda layer, but I have no idea since `'Tensor' object does not support item assignment`

3. I guess I can explicitely sort it, as

```
def sort_first_tree(x):
   x_front = tf.gather(x, [0, 1, 2, 3], axis=-1)
   x_tail = tf.gather(x, [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], axis=-1)
   x_front = tf.sort(x_front, axis=-1)
   return tf.concat([x_front, x_tail], axis=-1)
```

This works, but I am a little worried about performances.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# assuming your output layer is called 'output'
output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 9))

# sort the first three elements of each row in ascending order
sorted_output = tf.concat([tf.sort(output[:, :3], axis=1), output[:, 3:]], axis=1)
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I have already done, as written in the post

Comment: Yes but this works and dont worry about performance.